# Programmatically dismiss all React Native modal alerts/ dialogs?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

In our app, if one of our API calls returns that the user is unauthorized, we assume the user is logged out and take them back to the login screen. Due to background refresh based on web sockets, etc, this could happen any time… including when any number of native UI dialog-style components is on the screen, including Alerts, Android date/ time pickers, iOS action sheets, camera pickers, etc. Is there a way to ensure these things are dismissed when such an event happens?

Not sure about all of these, but I can confirm that Alerts, action sheets, and the camera picker UI remain on the screen in iOS after dismissing a view from the stack in React Navigation. It has been suggested in some cases to create a pure JavaScript component to replace some of these native modals (like an overlay on top of a view that looks like an alert but is really just a child of your current view). However, it seems impossible/ very difficult to replace 100% of these native modal components. Even if I replace the Alert and action sheet, I'm left with the camera/ photo picker, and I really don't want to build my own version of that.

Answer (score -2):

This might help - React Native v0.50.0 adds an `onDismiss` prop to `Modal` which allows you to pass a function that will be called once the modal has been dismissed.

Check out the updated docs here: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.51/docs/modal.html#ondismiss

And if you're curious here's the PR that made the change: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/a389ffbd84224b583e71cf7c1468409cbc91ec8e